# when i do rollback on liquibase, where can i find the logs of this rollback?

Tags: oracle, liquibase, history, rollback

I'm using liquibase with oracle database, after executing update command for a specific changeSet, and the log for this changeSet is inserted at DATABASECHANGELOG table, however if I executed a rollbackCount command to rollback that changeSet, the inserted log is deleted and i can't find the history of the changes that were executed and rolledback again.

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase's DATABASECHANGELOG table only records what's in the database. It's not an audit history tool.

For audit, you can look at using [Liquibase Hub](http://hub.liquibase.com) which records update and rollback operations so you'll have a record of when the operation was performed.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but is there any other way to audit the changes rather than using the hub as i'm working at a secure network that won't be able to access the hub, or if i can install a local version of the hub.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run rollback-*-sql command prior to running an actual rollback. For example, `rollback-count-sql` or `rollback-sql` or `rollback-to-date-sql`. These commands will output rollback SQL to console but not execute rollback on the database. You'll need to follow up with the actual rollback operation.

Run

```
liquibase rollback-count-sql 10
```

Examine the generated SQL or log it to a file. If happy with generated SQL then run:

```
liquibase rollback-count 10
```